# How to use xsl/xpath to count all child elements for which a custom function returns true?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to determine if all the items in a list pass a test.

I am using the following line:

```
<xsl:with-param name="passed" select="count($list/[fn:inRange(., 2, 5)]) = count($list)"/>
```

I am trying to send every child node in the list and applying my range tool (custom function, which works fine). I keep getting a syntax error.

The problem seems to be with the way I am calling it. 
Specifically, the following item:

```
count($list/[fn:inRange(., 2, 5)])
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression instead...

```
count($list[fn:inRange(., 2, 5)])
```

Alternatively, try writing the whole expression like this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="passed" select="not($list[not(fn:inRange(., 2, 5))]))"/>
```